# Xcode is giving "Product Packaging Utility Error" on compiling

Tags: ios, xcode

Following is the error description:

```
ProcessProductPackaging "" ...../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XYZ-fiiuqjozrqwvgzesmbchodjklrvl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XYZ.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/StLukes.build/XYZ.app.xcent
    cd "...../Documents/XYZ/"
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    builtin-productPackagingUtility -entitlements -format xml -o /Users/dmi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XYZ-fiiuqjozrqwvgzesmbchodjklrvl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XYZ.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/XYZ.build/XYZ.app.xcent
```

error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Answer (score 1):

One of my file in project - in my case(XYZ.entitlements) was under conflict in a merge but it was not giving any error while compiling in Xcode. 
After resolving its conflict build compiled successfully.